# 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, apache2, 17.04

Getting this error when trying to install the module:

```
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate
```

All solutions I found suggest adding 'multiverse' to apt sources, but they see to wokr only for previous version of Ubuntu. I have this (among others) in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` by default:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
```

I am assuming this module has been dropped from Ubuntu, but what would be the replacement for it? The proxy_fcgi module doesn't do the trick, as rewrites are not working out of the box and modifying them to add the [P] flag is not an option for me.

Comment: You could download it from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libapache2-mod-fastcgi and `sudo dpkg -i <package name>` to install it; it's under LTS, not sure how wise that is, probably friends on your use-case.

Comment: my use case is a development VM, so I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: worked perfectly so far! @pbhj feel free to post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Download the missing package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libapache2-mod-fastcgi and `sudo dpkg -i <package name>` to install it; it's under LTS so should get updates and fixes, but you'll have to manually check for them and apply them in the same way (or add a "xenial" entry in your apt .list files).

Not sure how wise this is, probably depends on your use-case; maybe not good for a production server!